i want to know how edge flow works?
I have added a plane as you can see in the picture and I have tried to give edge loop. the question is why the loop does not follow the path that I drawn with red marker. why it follows the upper position and also why it follows down why not go to the side edge in the x axis. it would be a great help if someone helps me and give me the basic idea.


Edges flow always from an edge of a quad to its opposite.
If you grab the vertex wich is in the center of the two top right triangles, and move it down and right, you will clearly see that this "nearly quad" makes its edge flow correctly according to this simple law.

And this is the correct way to make the flow at angle:

Or similarly, dissolving 3 vertices:

